# conditions to transport / conditions for transporting

Tags: verbs

Which of these sentences is correct?

> They create comfortable conditions to transport goods around the country.
>
> They create comfortable conditions for transporting goods around the country.

Additionally, if I don't write about any specific country, do I need "the"?

Answer (score 0):

Those two sentences are both correct. They mean the same thing, and are interchangeable.

If you are not writing about a specific country, you still need to use *some* article with "country". You can say, "... around **a** country," but just "... around country," is not right.

Comment: And what would be more proper in such a case - "around a country" or "around the country"?

Comment: Hard to say for sure without the specific context. In general though, I think a situation for "the" would arise more often than one where you would use "a"... If you have previously (prior sentence) *named* the country, or if you are discussing an individual country (even without a name), maybe a *general* country, but *one* country (in relation to other countries), use "the". If your sentence has no prior context about the concept of countries, and the statement would be true for *any* country, then use "a". Sorry to be so vague: it's a very "iffy" topic.

Comment: As an annoying quirk of English, it's quite idiomatic to say *transporting goods cross country*. No article is needed there, nor would it sound correct if one were added.